# How to solve task to study in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a task to study in Prolog

```
Y=.(.(1,[],.(2,.(a,.(b,[])))).
```

What is `Y`?
How to solve it?

Comment: `Y` is a variable. For the expression, see [9.2 Terms with a Special Notation](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse38) in Learn Prolog Now!

Comment: Note that you have 5 left parentheses and only 4 right ones. Also (at least in SWI) `=.` notation i not the same as `= .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typos. `.` is a binary functor — it must have only two arguments, always. Also, there must be a space between `=` and `.`, as they are used here as two different operators, not one operator:

```
Y=.(.(1,[] , .(2, .(a, .(b,[])))).
Y=.(.(1,[]), .(2, .(a, .(b,[])))).
    -------            ------- 
                  -------------
             -------------------
```

Testing:

```
2 ?- Y = .( .(1,[]), .(2, .(a, .(b,[])))).
Y = [[1], 2, a, b].
```

`Y` is a logical variable. You don't solve it, Prolog does. [`=/2` performs a unification](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2), and as a result, here, the logical variable `Y` gets instantiated with a value — here, the compound term describing, evidently, a list.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `Y` is a *logical variable* that happens to be *instantiated as a list*.

Comment: @lurker Isn't logical variable referring to a boolean variables?

Comment: @EugeneSh. not in this case. It's the general sense of logical, not the boolean sense.